# Using GDAL directly on windows

Tags: python, windows, gdal

Is there a possibility to use GDAL directly through MS_DOS? Most of the instructions I have seen requires one to install Python and its bindings.

Would it be possible to use GDAL after installing the self executable installation msi? Any other configuration steps required?

Thanks

Comment: you mean http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ ?

Comment: MS DOS? Do you mean `cmd.exe`?

Comment: There are thorough answers at [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows).

Comment: Thanks all! A few clarifications @monkut : I have used the binaries from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/

Comment: @wRAR : yah would like to use it on the ms-dos

Comment: @Mike Toews: Is there ways to do it without installing python?

Comment: You can use the command line utilities without Python, but they are limited to common used functions like format conversion, warping etc.

Comment: @user1538798 I don't think you understand what are you saying

Comment: @user1538798 MS-DOS was discontinued in 2000. Very few software are supported for that operating system today, and it is unlikely you are using this OS for GIS work. MS Windows, however, is supported by GDAL possibly back to either Win2k or XP and up to recent versions of Windows.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake. I will be using the command prompt from Windows 7 and not MS-DOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GDAL is supported on Microsoft Windows. However, there are several different ways to install it; see the options at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-to-install-gdal-with-python-on-windows

The simplest way is to use [OSGeo4w](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). To install a minimal GDAL command line setup, use the advanced mode of the installer to select one package: `gdal`. As some of the GDAL command line utilities are Python scripts, it will install its own version of Python as a dependency. After installation, use the OSGeo Shell from the Start menu for a command prompt.